# How can i make up slider with stop-points

Tags: c++, qt, scale, qslider

Excuse me if such a topic already exists. 
I want a custom slider for scaling my scene. Smth like the one in windows explorer, that changes folders' sizes. 
But in horizontal direction, and it hadn't exactly looks like that one. Should I use qss, or I  had to subclass QSlider and paint it by myself?

Comment: Do you want just want to see little icons in the along the slider's edge (instead of tick marks)?  And for the slider to snap to intervals along it's value range?

Comment: Whatever. My problem is that I can't image how it can be realised. It would be either Qwidget with subwidgets or it is just styled QSlider? And last point is user must knows, what he doing; i.e. I want to show him that when he will move slider through some stop-point the scale would be changed to another one (monthes, days etc).

Comment: @Juriy what did you do to solfe your problem? I have an similar problem and i'm looking for something to solfe it. Did you draw your own slider or did you find an other solution?

Comment: @retinotop as I remember, I used QtmSlider. And it is painted in paint event. Qss a litter poor to adjust custom slider view

Comment: @Juriy yes you are completely right. It's really poor and i think the QSlider is not really nice implemented - in scope of user interaction... But thx a lot for your reply. I've also used to implement an little workaround for my solution... ;)